# Azure API Management PolicyID (id) for context.LastError.PolicyId

Tags: azure-api-management

In the notes on error handling in Azure API management there is the following statement:

*All policies have an optional id attribute that can be added to the root element of the policy. If this attribute is present in a policy when an error condition occurs, the value of the attribute can be retrieved using the context.LastError.PolicyId property.*

Which means I can access this: context.LastError.PolicyId

I have tried this in my policy root node:

<policies id="1">

But my context.LastError.PolicyId is still empty or null.

I can't find any other posts on this.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to set ids on individual policies (cors, send-request, set-header, e.t.c). IF specified those would be presented in this property.

Comment: Ah I was setting them on <policies id=1... I'll give it a crack then mark your answer